# Multiple languages of website testing automation

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, automated-tests

How I can do verification for different language of website using testing automation tools selenium ....
Example
If the application have title page (apps on Google play) , I do verification by this title in selenium but if I want to do verification in spain or French language how !!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Automation of different languages can be tiresome.

One way to do is to have different translations in a datafile(config.properties) and compare based on the language user has logged-in.

For Eg:

Fr_txt: Bienvenue

Sp_txt: Bienvenido/a

These translations has to maintained and updated if changed.